# Advise to create a translator in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace, pattern-matching, replaceall

I want to make a **translator** ex: English to Spanish.

I want to translate a **large text** with a map for the translation.

```
HashMap <String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap <String, Object>();
hashmap.put("hello", "holla"); 
.
.
.
```

Witch **object** should I use to handle my inital text of 1000 words? A String or StringBuilder is fine ?

How can I do a large **replace**? Without **iterate** each word with each element of the map ?

I don't want take each word of the string, and see there is a match in my map

Maybe a multimap with the first letter of the word?

If you have any answer or advise thank you

Comment: I've no idea, what you're talking about. And trust me, almost no-one would have, with the current text of your question. So please explain a bit more. Probably if you've some code, that would be best put here for showing what you've tried.

Comment: "More computing sins are committed in the name of efficiency (without necessarily achieving it) than for any other single reason - including blind stupidity." Iterate over words, optimize it only it is too slow.

Comment: With a a text of 1000 words and 1000 words in my map, i get 1 million replace operations by traduction, i think it is too much

Comment: Assuming you have a text with 1000 unique words and a map with 1000 translations for those words, you will have to do one iteration over the text and do one lookup for each iteration. The looked up translation will also have to be added to the translated text. I don't think there is a simple way to make this more efficient, and if there is it will most likely be complicated and require more storage space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Translator {

    public enum Language {
        EN, ES
    }

    private static final String TRANSLATION_TEMPLATE = "translation_%s_%s.properties";
    private final Properties translations = new Properties();

    public Translator(Language from, Language to) {
        String translationFile = String.format(TRANSLATION_TEMPLATE, from, to);
        try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(translationFile)) {
            translations.load(is);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not read: " + translationFile, e);
        }
    }

    private String[] translate(String text) {
        String[] source = normalizeText(text);
        List<String> translation = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String sourceWord : source) {
            translation.add(translateWord(sourceWord));
        }
        return translation.toArray(new String[source.length]);
    }

    private String translateWord(String sourceWord) {
        Object value = translations.get(sourceWord);
        String translatedWord;
        if (value != null) {
            translatedWord = String.valueOf(value);
        }
        else {
            // if no translation is found, add the source word with a question mark
            translatedWord = sourceWord + "?";
        }
        return translatedWord;
    }

    private String[] normalizeText(String text) {
        String alphaText = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " ");
        return alphaText.split("\\s+");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Translator translator = new Translator(Language.EN, Language.ES);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(translator.translate("hello world!")));
    }
}
```

And put a file called 'translation_EN_ES.properties' on your classpath (e.g. src/main/resources) with:

```
hello=holla
world=mundo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the words before hand you could easily create a Regex Trie.
Then at runtime, compile the regex once. Then you are good to go.

To create the regex, download and install RegexFormat 5 [here](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl).

From the main menu, select *Tools -> Strings to Regex - Ternary Tree*
paste the list in the input box, then press the *Generate* button.
It spits out a full regex Trie that is as fast as any hash lookup there is.

Copy the compressed output from that dialog into *Rxform* tab (mdi) window.
Right click window to get the Context menu, select *Misc Utilities -> Line Wrap*
set it for about a 60 character width, press ok.

Next press the *C++* button from the windows toolbar to bring up the *MegaString*
dialog. Click make C-style strings *Lines Catenated-1* press OK.
Copy and paste the result into your Java source.

Use the regex in a Replace-All with callback.
In the callback use the match as a key into your hash table to return the
translation to replace.

Its simple, one pass and oh so fast.

For a more extreme example of the tool see [this](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/Samples/Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/_wl_A-Z__Compressed_Text_Multi_Lined.txt) regex of a 130,000 word dictionary.

Sample of the letter *X*

```
"(?:x(?:anth(?:a(?:m|n|te(?:s)?)|e(?:in|ne)|i(?:an|"
"c|n(?:e)?|um)|o(?:ma(?:s|ta)?|psia|us|xyl))|e(?:be"
"c(?:s)?|n(?:arthral|i(?:a(?:l)?|um)|o(?:biotic|cry"
"st(?:s)?|g(?:amy|enous|raft(?:s)?)|lith(?:s)?|mani"
"a|n|ph(?:ile(?:s)?|ob(?:e(?:s)?|ia|y)|ya)|time))|r"
"(?:a(?:fin(?:s)?|n(?:sis|tic)|rch|sia)|ic|o(?:derm"
"(?:a|i(?:a|c))|graphy|m(?:a(?:s|ta)?|orph(?:s)?)|p"
"h(?:agy|ily|yt(?:e(?:s)?|ic))|s(?:is|tom(?:a|ia))|"
"t(?:es|ic))))|i(?:pho(?:id(?:al)?|pag(?:ic|us)|sur"
"an))?|oan(?:a|on)|u|y(?:l(?:e(?:m|n(?:e(?:s)?|ol(?"
":s)?))|i(?:c|tol)|o(?:carp(?:s)?|g(?:en(?:ous)?|ra"
"ph(?:s|y)?)|id(?:in)?|l(?:ogy|s)?|m(?:a(?:s)?|eter"
"(?:s)?)|nic|ph(?:ag(?:an|e(?:s)?)|on(?:e(?:s)?|ic)"
")|rimba(?:s)?|se|tomous)|yl(?:s)?)|st(?:er(?:s)?|i"
"|o(?:i|s)|s|us)?)))"
```

Comment: @AdriaanKoster - Not novel. What the regex does is only match the keys in the source. Since the regex is a full Trie, its like putting a hash lookup of the keys within the regex.without the bother of having to come out of the regex. So it only comes out when it found a key. The substitution is then done replacing the source key with the hash _value_. Its basically a ternary spell checker within a regex. The speed advantage is on the order of 100 - 1000 or more say if you actually manually checked each word.